# Changing CSS styling with an if statement in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Context: I'm trying to change the color of a text according to a if statement (Green if `returnOfInvestment >= 0` red if this isn't true) however, it doesn't seem to be working. I've searched on SO already, but can't figure out why it isn't working as expected.

```js
var returnOfInvestment = (netProfit / initialInvestment.value) * 100;
var valEl = document.querySelector(".number dashtext-2");
var portfolioEl = document.querySelector(".number dashtext-3");

if (returnOfInvestment >= 0) {
  valEl.style.color = "green";
  portfolioEl.style.color = "green";
} else {
  valEl.style.color = "red";
  portfolioEl.style.color = "red";
}
```

```css
.dashtext-2 {
  color: #27b83f !important;
}

.dashtext-3 {
  color: #27b83f !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md">
  <div class="statistic-block block">
    <div class="progress-details d-flex align-items-end justify-content-between">
      <div class="title">
        <div class="icon"><i class="icon-bars"></i></div>
        <strong><div class="valdeval"></div></strong>
      </div>
      <div class="number dashtext-2">
        <div class="valorization"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md">
  <div class="statistic-block block">
    <div class="progress-details d-flex align-items-end justify-content-between">
      <div class="title">
        <div class="icon"><i class="icon-pie-chart"></i></div><strong> Portfolio</strong>
      </div>
      <div class="number dashtext-3">
        <div class="totalportfolio"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should avoid to use `.style` function in JS in 2021. The modern approach is to use `.classList` +
 `.add('class-name')` , `.remove('class-name')` or `.toggle('class-name')` to apply changes through CSS.
 This causes far less issues incl. possible specificity weight issues.

Comment: also note, that `!important` has the highest specificty weight. As such it also has a higher specificty weight then inline-style

Comment: Where did you define `netProfit`?

Comment: @tacoshy Thank you for your input! I'll search those up!

Comment: @DaniloIvanovic I don't show it on the code I provided as an example, but it is defined in my main code (I didn't put it here for simplicity since netProfit calls a bunch of other variables I created)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Give the elements you want to style a class and use CSS to apply a green text-color.
2. Create a class within CSS for a red text-color like: `.color-red { color: red; }`
3. Change the script slightly as below. Use `classList.remove('.color-red');` to remove the class that changes the text-color to red or the same function with `.add` instead of `.remove` to apply the class for the red tex-color.

```js
function changeStyle() {

  var returnOfInvestment = document.getElementById('input-number').value;
  var valEl = document.querySelector('.random-element'),
      portfolioEl = document.querySelector('.portfolio-element');

  if (returnOfInvestment >= 0) {
    valEl.classList.remove('color-red');
    portfolioEl.classList.remove('color-red');
  } else {
    valEl.classList.add('color-red');
    portfolioEl.classList.add('color-red');
  }
}
```

```css
.random-element,
.portfolio-element {
  color: green;
}

.color-red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="input-number" name="input-number" onchange="changeStyle()">

<h1 class="random-element">Random element</h1>
<h1 class="portfolio-element">Portfolio element</h1>
```

Alternativly you could add a specific class to all elements you want to change color for. Then you can use this instead:

```
var allEL = document.querySelectorAll('.class-name');

if (returnOfInvestment >= 0) {
    allEL.forEach(el => el.classList.remove('color-red'));
  } else {
    allEL.forEach(el => el.classList.add('color-red'));
  }
}
```

That will apply/remove the class of all elements with a specific class. Really helpfull if you need to apply changes to multiple elements.